# Calling rest API through docker container

Tags: angular, docker

I have developed backend Rest API using spring boot and frontEnd using angular 8 my question is I have deployed backend and frontend in the same server through docker-compose I need a way to make angular calling rest API through docker containers and network without exposing my backend rest API I have tried to call backend with its container name in angular but it is not working
API link example from angular  http://shop_soofybackendservice/api/departments

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:8.0.15
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
    volumes:
      - databasevolume:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - databasenetwork
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      labels: [ database=MYSQL_DATABASE ]


  soofybackendservice:
    image: tomcatsoofybackend:latest
    #build:
    #  context: ./onlineshopping/soofy-trade
    #  dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      mysqlhost: shop_database
      mysqlupassword: 123456
      mysqluname: root
      imagesPath: /home/ubuntu/images
    volumes:
      - imagesvolume:/home/ubuntu/images
    ports:
      - 81:8080
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - databasenetwork
      - backendnetwork
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      labels: [ backend=backendWep ]


  #tomcatsoofyfrontend
  #http://backend.medodolphin.com/
  soofyfrontendservice:
    image: mealfrontend:latest
    #build:
    #  context: ./onlineshopping/soofy-frontend
    #  dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 82:80
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - backendnetwork
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      labels: [ frontend=frontendWeb ]


volumes:
  databasevolume:
  imagesvolume:

networks:
  databasenetwork:
  backendnetwork:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper URL for communication between services (ex. `tomcatsoofyfrontend` calling the `soofybackendservice`) is the name of the service in the docker-compose. In your case it's `soofybackendservice`, therefore the endpoit is `http://soofybackendservice:8080/api/departments`

If your application is calling the endpoint from the remote browser/host, then you need to call `http://<<ip or the domain name of docker host>>:81/api/departments`.

Comment: Not working Note: I have added shop_ because when I run docker-compose I'm using this command docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml shop  and by default shop_ added to all services name

Comment: Your Angular application is on a public network, Internet, and know nothing about the local private network on which your backend is running. You need a proxy container sharing the same network as your backend and mapped to a public port.

Comment: @mtovmassian sure, I assumed the call is arriving from the `tomcatsoofyfrontend` container. I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski  your second answer is true and that I have already made it and working fine but my problem that ana one able to use my endpoint I know there are some things like JWT and auth2 but I'm thinking that I do not expose my endpoint and make the angular app use the endpoints through my private network so is there anything like that?

Comment: @HossamHany to talk to the end point you need to have network connection to it, so you can not avoid exposing endpoint on internet, however you can control and protect by adding security layer (ex. proxy, SSL, access certificates, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Angular is likely making client side calls. You need to [expose your api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) and configure the URL accordingly. You'll likely need to specify `localhost` in your API url.

Comment: ok, I can understand you but my question is there anything to not expose my API and access it through my private network through angular, or I must expose the API?